# How to do the countup with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create a count up with JavaScript and it isn't working

I did:

```
function increment (){
     for (var i = 0; i <= 100;  i++){
         text.innerHTML += parseInt(i)
      }
 }

setTimeout(increment, 200)
```

Comment: There is a spelling mistake in your for loop, you should not be checking the condition on I (capital i), but instead should be checking i. Javascript is a case sensitive language.

Comment: It was a typo, I have corrected it, the code doesn't run the way I want it to run

Comment: In the `for` loop you declare `i` but then use a capital `I` for the condition, change that to a lowercase `i`. You also use a colon instead of a semi colon after 100. There may also be an error with how you increment text. Adding a number to the innerHTML will result in something like "123456...100" rather than what you want which is the sum of 0 to 100.

Comment: The semicolon is a typo..  i want the number to increase after every .2seconds. like an animation

Comment: Also, right after your condition in your `for` loop, you have a `:`, where it should be a semicolon. This is giving you an error.

Edit: Nvm, you just posted you said it was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval` in order to make an actual count up, if that's what you wanted to achieve:

```js
function countUp() {
  var i = 0; // a counter which is displayed every 100ms

   // create interval which fires the callback every 100ms.
   // `interval` holds the interval ID, which is later used to clear the
   // interval (stop calling the callback)
  var interval = setInterval(function() { 

    text.innerHTML = i++; // write `i` and increment
    
    // if `i` is grater than 100 then clear the interval (stop calling the callback)
    if (i > 100) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 100);
}

countUp();
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: It worked.. Thanks so much. Please can you explain the code a little bit?

Comment: Sure, I've added some comments to the code. Does it help?

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot